# display formula expression with inputs rather that its result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose Cell `A1` contains the value `2` and Cell `A2` contains the value `3`.

Suppose Cell `A3` has the formula `=A1*A2`.

Instead of `A3` showing the product of the numbers in `A1` and `A2`, I'd like it to show "`2*3`".

So that e.g. if I change the value in `A1` to `7`, `A3` should now show `7*3`. Can this be done?

Comment: @Fadi this is nontrivial enough to be an (accepted) answer if you ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show formula instead of the result, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to toggle them.

If you only need to show that expression in that particular cell all the time, try this:

```
=A1&"*"&A2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
=A1&CHAR(42)&A2
```